# Does pandas.read_csv() has the way to remove '\s' and '\t' char when reads the a file into DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iostream

I need to read a .csv file into a DataFrame, but the file contains /s and /t characters that compromise further analysis. Is it better to manipulate the file first and delete the \s \t char? Or pandas.read_csv() has a way to do it?

I tried modifying the .csv file, but it seems to be not a good solution for me, specially if the code is working in specific environment that requieres permission to write on Disc.

```
with open(file, 'r+') as fl:
    stream = str()
    for char in fl.read():
        if char != ' ':
            stream += char
        fl.seek(0)
        fl.flush()
        fl.write(stream)
data = pd.read_csv(file)
```

For me it would be better if I can do this when reading (pd.read_csv()) or with the data in pandas.DataFrame() object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I used up until now is loading the data into DataFrame and then invoking `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`. I hope this is what you meant.